# writing a char on gotoxy(80, 25) position without having cursor moved to new line

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, dosbox

I am trying to draw a frame in my output.

My windows size is 80x25 (width x height in character)

I have drawn all lines successfully using below code. But writing to very last point (80, 25) is getting the cursor moved to the next line that I can not handle.

My Code is as below:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void DrawFrame(int);
void DrawHoriLine(int, int, int, int, int);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    DrawFrame(GREEN);
    getch();
}

void DrawFrame(int color)
{
    DrawHoriLine(2,  1, 78, 205, color);
    DrawHoriLine(2,  3, 78, 196, color);
    DrawHoriLine(2, 22, 78, 196, color);
    DrawHoriLine(2, 24, 78, 205, color);
    gotoxy(1, 3);   cprintf("%c", 198);
    gotoxy(80, 3);  cprintf("%c", 181);
    gotoxy(1, 1);   cprintf("%c", 213);
    gotoxy(80, 1);  cprintf("%c", 184);
    gotoxy(1, 25);  cprintf("%c", 212);
    gotoxy(80, 25); cprintf("%c", 190);  //*** Here is problem
}

void DrawHoriLine(int x, int y, int length, int charCode, int color)
{
    gotoxy(x, y);
    textcolor(color);
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        cprintf("%c", charCode);
}
```

As 25 is the last line and moving cursor to next line is making my frame ill displayed. All horizontal lines previously drawn moved upward by one.

I know this is not an unusual behavior.
But is not there any other option to get rid of this..? If not than I will not be able to use last line in my frame.

I am running Turbo C++ in Windows 8 x64 OS using DosBox. So I can not set the window height from window's properties manually that I always used to do.

Comment: You could try `SetConsoleCursorPosition` to set it back to the top line. If that doesn't work, perhaps `ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a compiler which is 20 years old?

Comment: No.. :-( @chris these functions are not working in Turbo C++. I searched for these in help index there is nothing like this

Comment: @user93353 because GCC 4.6 is toooo mainstream :P

Comment: I remember I had that problem, around 1997, in Turbo Pascal. I just settled for 24 lines. >:)

Comment: I too do not want to use this.. and actually a C# programmer. But I am developing a project for my sister in 10th std. They bound us to use turbo c++ @user93353

Comment: Who are `they`? The Government?

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi Why don't you go shoot your sister's teacher? Forcing students to deprecated, outdated, irrespective-to-standards tools is a huge antipedagogical pattern and is brainless.

Comment: and what if this includes in guidelines from the board..? @H2CO3

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi Well, without wanting to go too off-topic: seriously, this is bad and they should feel bad... I understand you have no control above this, but still...

Comment: I've seen this scenario before.  The teacher is comfortable with an old technology and can't, or won't learn, new technology.  His rational is, he's teaching concepts and the tool doesn't matter.  But why not teach the concepts with a modern tool?  (PS:  I've used and liked Turbo C++)

Comment: @SteveWellens - C++ has changed radically since Turbo C++ was released. I don't think turbo C++ even has support for basic templates.

Comment: Board guidelines instructs usage of TC++ ? Which board ?

Comment: @user93353 - Why are you telling me this?  I'm not defending it, just explaining it.

Comment: This problem can not be solved other than by writing your own functions to manipulate the screen data. Once you print at the very bottom of the screen, it will scroll because it moves off the screen. Yes, it would be possible to alter the BIOS so that it doesn't do this until there is actually something to write to the first position on the next line, but I doubt anyone wants to do that right now. I had some code to poke characters into the display memory directly. If I remember right, it's 80 x 25 bytes, the first byte is a character, the second the attribute (or is it the other way around)

Comment: than.. can u all pls suggest me a compiler with IDE to develop C++ console based apps that work most likely to Turbo C++/Borland C++..??

Comment: Why the h**l would you want something that works like something that wasn't that great 30 years ago when it first came out? Sure, it was a little better than the competitors, but in no way fantastic. Visual Studio Express edition is free, available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express

Comment: This is the way terminals have worked, always. Not likely to change!

Comment: @MatsPetersson I already have VS2012 Ultimate installed. But C++ works in a very different way in compare to TC. I had given it a try.

Comment: What's different? It certainly compiles to better code [as in, it runs much faster], I can tell you that. It gives you more/better warnings. It allows you to use Windows API functions [may not be a benefit if you prefer Unix API, but never mind that now]. You are learning "how to do it the old way". I just don't see the point in using a very old compiler that isn't being produced any more. And doesn't support the TWO latest C++ standards!

Comment: @MatsPetersson I selected Win32 console app from templates list. Plenty of files added to the projects I can't understand. `cout` not working even after including `iostream`. `iostream.h` is an error while `conio.h` not (notice .h). I have 4+ yr exp in C# (both client & web app). But I think I will have to learn VC++ from the ground. I need a language much similar to classical C++.
Just giving a try to `CodeBlocks with mingw gcc`.

Comment: What you mean is that you didn't `add using namespace std;` to your code, so therefore the compiler told you it didn't know what `cout` is? And if you actually get to an interview, and the interviewer asks about namespaces, you'd probably be expected to know at least some rudimentary parts of it, right? Learning how to use the MODERN versions of a language, even if it means a few more characters to type [no more than in this thread tho'] is really a good idea. BUt be aware that older variants of the language exists - I'm not aware of any commercial development using Turbo C tho'.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi - `iostream.h` is long deprecated in c++. You need to `#include <iostream>`. You need to do `using namespace std;` or `std::cout`. This is `C++` as of today. What do you do when you use TC++ is that you are learning 20 year old C++.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal text mode resolution is 80 x 24 . Draw upto 24 instead of 25 , maybe ?

And get rid of TC as soon as possible. Checkout ncurses after you get rid of TC.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, and certainly should have a comment to suggest why!

Comment: No idea why it was down-voted. The text terminal has text resolution 80 x 24. And 80 x 24 x 2 bytes are reserved for this text mode memory in the 0xb8000 area in real mode, when the system is booted. one byte for text colour one for ASCII value.

Comment: On PCs you have always had 25 lines. See [PC common text modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode#PC_common_text_modes).

Comment: Not a problem. It would have been better if the downvoter explained the cause, that would help me correct the problem, that's how stackexchange site works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extend the 24/25 line limit. The Command Prompt should be ale to scroll for quite a while.